# How to create a conan package including tests for a header only library which can be packaged on all platforms

Tags: c++, cmake, conan, ctest

I'm trying to create a header only package with conan which is based on CMake and CTest. It's as empty as possible and just contains two tests with empty `main()` functions.

While `conan create . conantest/stable` works fine on linux it stop with the error

```
conantest/0.1@conantest/stable: ERROR: Package '...' build failed
conantest/0.1@conantest/stable: WARN: Build folder C:\Users\...\.conan\data\conantest\0.1\conantest\stable\build\...
ERROR: conantest/0.1@conantest/stable: Error in build() method, line 17
        cmake.test()
        ConanException: Error 1 while executing cmake --build "C:\Users\...\.conan\data\conantest\0.1\conantest\stable\build\..." --target test
```

on windows.

The problem is that on windows with this example `cmake.test()` doesn't invoke the *multi-config* `RUN_TESTS` target [as described here](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/build_helpers/cmake.html#test) but `test`.

From the docs i got the impression that it should distinguish automatically but i also don't know if that's correct or what's missing to enable this automatism.

It is possible to hint at the build type by providing settings:

```
settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
```

> When Conan generates a compiled binary for a package with a given
> combination of the settings above, it generates a unique ID for that
> binary by hashing the current values of these settings.

but [as described here](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#settings) usually those are set to `None` explicitely for header only libraries.

As i understand it, the tests are only built and executed during packaging but their binary form is not part of the package. Is there a way to define the recipe for only one unique ID while still being able to build and run the tests during packaging on any platform?

The test project is available [on git](https://github.com/jessesna/conantest1).

These are its contents:

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.0)
project(conantest VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(conantest1 conantest1.cpp)
add_test(conantest1 conantest1)
add_executable(conantest2 conantest2.cpp)
add_test(conantest2 conantest2)
```

*conanfile.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from conans import ConanFile, CMake

class ConantestConan(ConanFile):
    name = "conantest"
    version = "0.1"
    generators = "cmake"
    exports_sources = "*"
    no_copy_source = True

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()
        cmake.test()
    def package(self):
        self.copy("*.hpp")
    def package_id(self):
        self.info.header_only()
```

*conantest1.cpp and conantest2.cpp*

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main() {
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You can try adding config name as args `cmake.test(args=['--', 'ARGS=--config %s'] % self.settings.build_type)`

Comment: @uilianries from [the description](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/build_helpers/cmake.html#test) i got the impression that conan would choose the right target automatically: "If not defined RUN_TESTS or test will be used".

I also found the [cmake property GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG.html) and some mentions of [conanbuildinfo_multi.cmake](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.7/integrations/cmake/cmake_multi_generator.html#creating-packages) but tbh i'm not sure if this is even remotly related.

Comment: The problem is you don't have settings declared in your recipe. I still can use same package ID. Without settings, Conan has no hint about build type.

Comment: @uilianries i edited the question.
As far as i understand the tests are only built and run during packaging but are themselfes in binary form not part of the package. Artificially adding a unique ID for binaries which are not part of the package seems wrong. Is there a way to specify those settings only for the Ctest part of the build? Here's the [settings documentation](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#settings) for reference.

Comment: No. Because your package is header-only, it will use the same package ID, doesn't matter what build type did you use. Still, if you want to build with a specific build type, you MUST add settings. The package ID will be the same, but at least you can control between Release/Debug for your unit tests, Conan was not designed for such advanced CTest settings, you are mixing different thing.

Comment: What you can do is moving your tests to [test_package](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/getting_started.html#the-test-package-folder) and running from there. Test package can use full settings and consume your header-only. However, test_package is not designed for unit tests, but for package validation only (run a simple test).